# XML parsing using xstream

Tags: xml, xstream

I have the following XML structure that I am parsing into the classes mentioned below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<OrderDiscount xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Status>Failed</Status>
  <Errors>Error : Customer 00000037 not found : Product 51 D0003 not found</Errors>
  <DeliveryID>00000037</DeliveryID>
  <CarriageAmount>0</CarriageAmount>
  <TotalDiscount>0</TotalDiscount>
  <OrderLines>
    <Warehouse>51</Warehouse>
    <Product>D0003</Product>
    <ContractPrice>N</ContractPrice>
    <UnitOfSale>20</UnitOfSale>
    <Ordered>1</Ordered>
    <ListPrice>10</ListPrice>
    <NetPrice>10</NetPrice>
    <NewNetPrice>0</NewNetPrice>
  </OrderLines>
</OrderDiscount>
```

Here, we can have multiple instances of `<OrderLines>`. I am trying to parse it using the following 2 classes

```
import java.util.List;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;

/**
 * @author nka
 *
 */

@XStreamAlias("OrderDiscount")
public class OrderDiscount {


    @XStreamAlias("Status")
    private String Status;

    @XStreamAlias("Errors")
    private String Errors;

    @XStreamAlias("DeliveryID")
    private String DeliveryID;

    @XStreamAlias("CarriageAmount")
    private String CarriageAmount;

    @XStreamAlias("TotalDiscount")
    private String TotalDiscount;

    @XStreamAlias("OrderLines")
    private List<OrderLines> OrderLines;

}
```

2nd Class:

```
public class OrderLines {

    @XStreamAlias("Warehouse")
    private String Warehouse;

    @XStreamAlias("Product")
    private String Product;

    @XStreamAlias("ContractPrice")
    private String ContractPrice;

    @XStreamAlias("UnitOfSale")
    private String UnitOfSale;

    @XStreamAlias("Ordered")
    private String Ordered;

    @XStreamAlias("ListPrice")
    private String ListPrice;

    @XStreamAlias("NetPrice")
    private String NetPrice;

    @XStreamAlias("NewNetPrice")
    private String NewNetPrice;
}
```

I am using the following code to parse it:

```
    OrderDiscount orderDiscount = null;

    final XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
    xstream.processAnnotations(OrderDiscount.class);
    xstream.processAnnotations(OrderLines.class);

    orderDiscount = (OrderDiscount) xstream.fromXML(response);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Target exception: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Warehouse : Warehouse : Warehouse : Warehouse
---- Debugging information ----
message             : Warehouse : Warehouse
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : Warehouse : Warehouse
class               : uk.co.portaltech.quicklive.thirdparty.datel.OrderDiscount
required-type       : java.util.ArrayList
path                : /OrderDiscount/OrderLines/Warehouse
line number         : 1
-------------------------------
```

Can someone please help me to correct the structure of my Java OBJECTS to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
 custom handler for ur XML parsing in more generic way so that it can parse all the pojo classes depending on the annotations